# How to read Value.Value property of ComboBox Automation Element

Tags: c#, automation, ui-automation

I am creating simple automation application and I am using Windows 10. 
I have written function that will return actual text of comboBox from AutomationElement.
Please check the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/iHATwpvl390k.

```
public static string GetText(AutomationElement element)
{
    object patternProvider;
    if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern, out patternProvider))
    {
        TextPattern txtPattern = patternProvider as TextPattern;
        return txtPattern.DocumentRange.GetText(-1);
    }
    if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out patternProvider))
    {
        ValuePattern valuePatternProvider = patternProvider as ValuePattern;
        return valuePatternProvider.Current.Value;
    }
    Logger.Log("Could not retrieve text" + element.Current.Name);
    return string.Empty;
}
```

This function always returm empty string. ComboBox IsValuePatternAvailableProperty is true in Inspect tool. 
Please check into screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/MYZ7gYwCX12S

I am not able to access Value.Value property of Automation Element.

Why I can not get actual value from ValuePattern even if IsValuePatternAvailableProperty is true?

Comment: Can't reproduce. A code like this: `MessageBox.Show(GetText(AutomationElement.FromHandle(comboBox1.Handle)))` with a simple winforms ComboBox with some items returns the selected item value. Please share your full reproducing code